# "Have questions", how to use the correct sentence to feedback "Have they finished painting the office yet?"

Tags: questions, exam-questions, perfect-constructions

How to response Q&A

> Question sentence :
>         Have they finished painting the office yet?
>
> Answers:
>       1. Yes, they finished yesterday.
>       2. No, he's still painting the walls.
>       3. No, we've just started

Which one is correct and how to modify other incorrect answer to correct sentence
this question is from TOEIC test
PS:http://www.english-test.net/toeic/listening/have_they_finished_painting_the_office_yet.html

thanks

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three TENSES are correct.

In (1), it was a good choice to use "finished" with an -ed, because the action is over and done with.

In (2), you followed the present progressive form perfectly: a present conjugation of *to be* that matches the subject paired with a present participle (i.e., an -ing word).

In (3), the use of *have* was smart since the effects of having just started will continue into the future.

Since they question was about if "**they**" have finished, I would change the "he" in (2) and the "we" in (3) to "they," just to be consistent.

Great job, and best of luck to you! —C.T.

Comment: Hi thank for your answer but unfortunately this question is from TOEIC test , so that do you have any idea ,(answer is A)

Comment: @willie Then yes, the answer is A, because it is the only one that uses "they" like the questions does. Thank you for responding!

Comment: you mean , when i change "They" for B and C ,it will be correct  ????

Comment: You got it @willie!! Although for (2) you will need to say "they are" instead of "they is"